# What did it mean for Saul to make David's father's house free?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, king-saul

In [1 Samuel 17:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a17.htm#25) it says:

> And the men of Israel said: 'Have ye seen this man that is come up? surely to taunt Israel is he come up; and it shall be, that the man who killeth him, the king will enrich him with great riches, and will give him his daughter, and **make his father's house free in Israel.**'

What did it mean to have your father's house be free?

Answer (score 4):

> 1. And the men of Israel said, "Have you seen this man who is coming up, for he is coming up to taunt Israel? And it will be, that the man who will kill him, the King will enrich him with great riches, and he will give him his daughter, and he will make his father's house free in Israel."
>
> Rashi: "'And he will make his father’s house free': from the things mentioned in the laws of the kingdom."

[Translation from Chabad's Tanach with Rashi site.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15846/showrashi/true#v25)